# Difference between ordinate and abscissa.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

While explaining the use of integrals in finding the area under a curve *y=f(x)*, my book gives the following explanation :

> We can think of the total area A of the region between x-axis, **ordinates x = a, x = b** and the curve y = f (x) as the result of adding up the elementary areas of thin strips across the region PQRSP.

[This is the image of the graph provided for reference.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOCmM.jpg

Now, my doubt is this: 
Why does it say the ***ordinates*** x=a and x=b? As far as I know, ordinate is the y-coordinate and abscissa is the x-coordinate in the ordered pair (x,y) in the Cartesian plane.

Answer (score 1):

The curve $x=a$ is the vertical line that goes through $(a,0)$ in the plane. If you write it as $\{(a,y)\mid y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, you can see that the parameter that fluctuates is the ordinate $y$, hence the name.

Comment: But even here, 'a' is still the x-coordinate (i.e. abscissa). Why do we name it on the basis of the parameter that fluctuates?

Comment: @ag_dhruv As far as I know, both names are used. As long as you have 'x=', it makes sense.